# how to change font formatting in Quarto pptx

Tags: r, fonts, powerpoint, quarto

I am creating a pptx with Quarto in R. To change the default font format I tried to change **mainfont** parameter. But when I render it, the final pptx file is having the default font (Calibri). Here is my YAML of the file. How to cutomise fonts when rendering a Quarto file as pptx? Thanks in advance.

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Satya"
format: pptx
mainfont: "Times New Roman"
---

Even
```

Comment: TBMK you have to create a custom pptx template for which you set your desired font. See https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/powerpoint.html#creating-a-template on how to create a custom template.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing the pptx template in the PowerPoint application. Instructions on creating a pptx template are here: https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/powerpoint.html#creating-a-template

Open your template.pptx in PowerPoint. Go to View > Slide Master. Open the layout you want to edit and adjust the font family and size. Save the changes and re-render your Quarto doc. The fonts should match what you set in Slide Master