# How to change font size in figure caption in a pptx rendered by quarto and pandoc?

Tags: r, powerpoint, pandoc, quarto

I am rendering powerpoint slide decks using Quarto. I am successfully theming my powerpoint slide deck using a reference doc specified in yaml and can change many slide layout attributes by changing the master slides.

However, I can't seem to find the master slide attribute that changes the caption font size. Irrespective of my changes to the master slides, the caption font under the figure always seems to be 18 pt. I would like it to be smaller.

These related posts don't (currently) solve my problem:

[how to change font formatting in Quarto pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74679348/how-to-change-font-formatting-in-quarto-pptx)

[Changing the caption font size, color, and style in PPTX qmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75009154/changing-the-caption-font-size-color-and-style-in-pptx-qmd#comment132487987_75009154)

The [pandoc](https://www.uv.es/wikibase/doc/cas/pandoc_manual_instalado.wiki?53) documentation suggests that captions are styled as their own class. It's not clear to me if it would be helpful (or possible) to somehow modify the caption class with quarto when rendering the pptx.

Can you specify a custom css style sheet when rendering a powerpoint slide deck?

My MRE (I can't provide the exact template I'm using):

```
---
title: "Captions for Figures"
format:
  pptx:
    reference-doc: my_pptx_template.potx
    slide-level: 1
---

# Slide with Figure

![The Stack Overflow Logo](https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png){#fig-stackoverflow}
```